# How can I set the default font size of inline math mode?

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, inline

is there any way to set the default size of inline math mode to \LARGE?

I don't want to type \LARGE$x$ every time I want to enter math mode
I want \LARGE to be the default

Comment: Do you *really* want something like in [this picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQAOm.png)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard classes for 10pt option `\LARGE` is 17pt so you can declare 17pt math sizes for 10pt text, This affects display as well as inline math, doing just inline would be harder as it's not directly supported to separate the two in LaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathSizes{10}{17}{12}{9}
\begin{document}

One $x$ two $\sin^2+\cos^2$  three $\frac{a}{b}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason, it didn't work with me yesterday, but somehow it worked today, thank you, sir, much appreciated. I have almost replaced about 60 \LARGE commands in my documents now .

Comment: @abbas.1 have to ask why do you want this? I can understand making all the text large if that is needed but why just math?

Comment: I want to actually enlarge the whole thing but I'm using arabic text and using the command \setmainfont to set the size of the font. I'm new to latex and would like to hear if there's any better way to do it.

Comment: @abbas.1 if you are using the font scale that means you are telling latex to load a 20pt fornt (or whatever) when a 10pt font is requested, that means that basically everything will be out. It is just intended for small adjustments to make two fonts look visually the same size of one "10pt" font looks bigger than another. Better to load the fonts at natural size but then declare a larger default document font size like the `[12pt]` option or see the extsizes package for a larger range of sizes

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. David. I really appreciate the information, I will use your suggestions in my next project and stop using the hardcoded approach, I'm grateful for your support.